# ROT13 encryption code in c fails for lowercase

Tags: c, encryption, rot13

This is my code for the ROT13 cipher.
It works with upper case but when i give in hello as the input , it returns [X__b      can anyone help me out here ...

```
void encrypt(char *cipher,int key) 
{
    int i = 0;
    while(cipher[i] != '\n') 
    {
        if(isalpha(cipher[i]))
        {
            if((cipher[i] + key) > 'Z' || (cipher[i] + key) > 'z')
            {
                cipher[i] = cipher[i] + key - 26;
            }
            else if((cipher[i] + key) >= 'a' && (cipher[i] + key) <= 'z')
            {
                cipher[i] = cipher[i] + key;
            }
            else if((cipher[i] + key) >= 'A' && (cipher[i] + key) <= 'Z')
            {
                cipher[i] = cipher[i] + key;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something very wrong is going on with your braces...

Comment: The braces are fine this is just a part of my code where there is a problem

Comment: Ok, in that case, something very wrong is going on with your indentation...

Comment: Did you try to use a *debugger* and single-step through your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition

```
f((cipher[i] + key) > 'Z' || (cipher[i] + key) > 'z')
```

will be true for ALL lowercase letters, the second part `(cipher[i] + key) > 'z'` being redundant